# How to map json object to string while using <-map["xx"]

Tags: swift, objectmapper

I need to transform a json object to string while mapping but the fromJSON is always nil.

I am providing a piece of code in which i think that I should not be getting nil in `value`. I supposed that I should get the json that is under "a.b"

```swift
   func mapping(map: Map) {
        b <- (map["a.b"], TransformOf<String, String>(fromJSON: { value in print("json \(value)"); return String(value) }, toJSON: { $0.map { String($0) } }))
    }
```

the json from which I am trying to map looks something like this

```swift
{
"a" : {
       "b" : { ..... } <- this is the piece I need as string
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at

[Using JSON with custom types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types)

which contains a working playground for converting JSON using Swift Codable